# Html2ps cakephp not passing variables

Tags: cakephp, html2pdf

I was using this tutorial http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/Casmo/2010/06/26/creating-pdf-files-with-html2ps-html2pdf to set up html2ps with cakePhp.

Everything is ok but when I am fetching some article from my database and pass it to the PDF view I am not getting any data. When I pass some string variable it is visible in the pdf view.

Can you suggest me what can cause that?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show some code in which you fetch the database data and pass it to the PDF view? Might it be that your data is a empty? Are you sure the data you pass through is a string and not an array?

Comment: $article = $this->Article->findById($articleId); $this->set('article',$article); It is not possible that this entry is empty in database,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this problem was connected to my other question which I have asked on stackoverflow, and which you can read here [Cake php default bahaviour for Translate behaviour not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7400929/cake-php-default-bahaviour-for-translate-behaviour-not-working).

After solving it this question also is answered. The data was not passing because there was a problem with translation - it simply was not downloading from the database. Read the above thread to learn more.

Thx anyway vindia for your answer.