# Cake php default bahaviour for Translate behaviour not working

Tags: cakephp, internationalization, translation, behavior

Can anyone suggest me why when there are no translation for a field it is returned empty, and not with the default translation?

I will appreciate all suggestions...

Can`t tell what part of my code you want to see, because it is all straight forward from www.book.cake.org. So i pasting some code:

Model definition:

```
<?php
class Article extends AppModel
{
    var $useTable = 'nc_articles';
    var $name = 'Article';
    var $actsAs = array(
        'Translate' => array(
        'title', 'content', 'meta_key_words','meta_description'
        )
    );
    // Use a different model
    var $translateModel = 'ArticlesI18n';
    // Use a different table for translateModel
    var $translateTable = 'nc_articles_i18ns';
    var $belongsTo = array(
        'Author' => array('className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'author_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => array(),
            'order' => '',
            'counterCache' => ''),       
        'Modifier' => array('className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'modifier_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => array(),
            'order' => '',
            'counterCache' => ''),   
        'Category' => array('className' => 'ArticlesCategory',
            'foreignKey' => 'category_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => array(),
            'order' => '',
            'counterCache' => ''),   
        'Layout' => array('className' => 'Layout',
            'foreignKey' => 'layout_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => array(),
            'order' => '',
            'counterCache' => ''),        
        );
    var $hasMany = array(
        'Comments' => array(
            'className' => 'ArticlesComment',
            'foreignKey' => 'article_id',
            'conditions' => array(),
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            //'dependent'=> true When dependent is set to true, recursive model deletion is possible. In this example, Comment records will be deleted when their associated User record has been deleted. 
            )
        ); 


}
?>
```

And then the function where I am changing Language:

```
function setLanguage($languageCode='pol')
{
    $this->Session->write('Config.language', $languageCode);
    $this->redirect($this->referer());
}
```

Would you like to see something more?

Comment: Hard to say anything without seeing any code.

Comment: added something to my question

Comment: The code in the manual works. If it didn't, I'm quite sure someone would have noticed by now.  Please paste *your* code.

Comment: I have updated my question with code sample

Comment: in my opinion it is not true that it is a default behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me answer my own question. There were few more things I had to write more. First of all I had to declare my Config.language in core.php then for Every model which is translated I had to declare a local variable which is an array of language codes

```
$this->Article->array('en','pol');
```

And that's how I managed the problem. But now queries for translation are very long and I am facing an optimization problem.